# Apache and httpd running but not opening in browser http://<ipaddress>

Tags: php, html, apache

I am facing problem to access Apache from browser[ **http://** ]. Following are the details related to apache config:

- I have install apache on centos 7.2 and using iptables instead firewalld .
- Apache is runnning on port 80

  ```html
  [root@VMAS04 ~]# netstat -anp | grep 80
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10419/httpd
  ```
- Firewall rules in iptables are :

  ```html
      [root@VMAS04 ~]# iptables -S
      -P INPUT ACCEPT
      -P FORWARD ACCEPT
      -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
      -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
      -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
      -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
      -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
  ```
- I tried "telnet localhost 80" which giving "**HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**"

```html
 [root@VMAS04 ~]# telnet localhost 80
    Trying ::1...
    telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    hi
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    Date: Sat, 13 May 2017 06:06:53 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16
    Content-Length: 226
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
    </p>
    </body></html>
    Connection closed by foreign host.
```

can anyone help me on this . very thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe localhost:80 in the web browser?

Comment: What does "not opening in browser" mean, is there any error?

Comment: http://<ipaddress>:80  should open a default page of apache.